# htaccess - cut out the question mark if there is one at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is such a code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)srp=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)q=
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html(?!/amp/).+$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly, but if the link is like this:

```
website.com/post.html?
```

In this case, the question mark remains. How can I delete it in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply check for an empty query string since the `QUERY_STRING` server variable is defined and empty regardless of whether the trailing `?` is present or not.

To remove a stray `?` at the end of the URL-path (essentially an empty query string) you can check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*\?\s
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,L,R=301]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the query string. This is the preferred way to remove the query string on Apache 2.4, as opposed to appending a `?` to the *substitution* string.

`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the HTTP request headers and contains a string of the form:

```
GET /post.html? HTTP/1.1
```

So, the regex `\s[^?]*\?\s` matches a literal `?` followed by a *space* at the end of the URL-path (avoiding a `?` that could occur at the end of a non-empty query string). For example:

- `/post.html?` redirected to `/post.html`
- `/post.html?foo=1?` - no redirect, since the final `?` is part of the `foo` URL parameter *value*.

*Aside:* You shouldn't surround each block in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper unless the directives are optional. (And even then the directives should be grouped together.)